# How do I include the Nuxt Layout component in a Jest / Nuxt page test?

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, nuxt.js

we are trying to write some high level / e2e jest tests in our vuejs/nuxt project. The goal is to be able to test some interactions between components at the Nuxt Page level. To accomplish this I'm doing a (deep) mount of the page component but the resulting wrapper only contains that page component, and its child components. In unit tests this is exactly what we would want, as the layout should be tested separately. However, in this case we want the page to be wrapped in the layout so we can test the interaction between the page and the components in the layout. Does anyone know if there is a way to do this? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This is not a proper e2e because you'll end up testing not real behaviour but something else that resembles it according to your expectations. A correct one will be something like https://dev.to/bawa_geek/how-to-setup-jest-testing-in-nuxt-js-project-5c84

Comment: Thanks for your comment Estus. This project already contains several thousand regular unit test written as you suggested, plus we have a suite of Selenium tests. We have new features we would like to test with Jest rather than Selenium so we are looking into the question I posted above. Thanks!

Comment: There's more than one way to do e2e with Jest. But basically it's either a setup that the link describes, or Jest+headless browser (Playwright for several engines)